# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1309٫5'

Tags: python-3.x, string, integer, converters, object-literal

```py
Stud_results.total = Stud_results.total.astype(int)
```

When I tried to convert data type from String to Int I got this message:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1309٫5'

Comment: You get the error because your input does not represent an integer. Why do you think this should have worked? What is your desired result?

Comment: `Stud_results.total` is a pandas Series?

Comment: There is a weird character (`٫`). This could be problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = ['2','1,565','543','2,322','3,756','6,454']

splited_list = [i.split(',') for i in data]

converted_list = [int(''.join(i)) for i in splited_list]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow @Umesh Tikhe! Please elaborate on your answer, so the asker can learn from it for the future.

Comment: If you have list in which the number are in string format and comma at thousand our million's place that can be remove and convert the list into integer format. This is data cleaning for any data science project

Answer (score 0):

you can manipulate your string to keep only what is before comma than to convert to `int`:

```
Stud_results.total = Stud_results.total.str.split(',').str[0].astype(int)
```

if that is not a comma you can also use:

```
my_weird_char = '٫'
Stud_results.total = Stud_results.total.str.split(my_wierd_char).str[0].astype(int)
```